# Why does Twitter's API provide a way to programmatically create "Likes," if it goes against their Automation rules?

Tags: rest, twitter, automation, social-media-like

I was looking into using [Twitter's official REST API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index) for automatically liking specific posts that fit certain conditions.

I looked into the API reference to see if this was possible—and in fact, there *is* and endpoint for doing this:

- [*"POST favorites/create"* - API reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-favorites-create)

However, looking at Twitter's policies—specifically ["*Automation rules*"](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation), it would seem that automating this behavior is explicitly prohibited:

> **D. Automated actions you take on Tweets or accounts**
>
> Automated likes: You may not like Tweets in an automated manner.

This leads to my question: If automating likes in Twitter goes explicitly against the rules, why do they provide an endpoint for this behavior in their official API for developers?

Comment: Automating this is prohibited, as is automating this in bulk. Using the API to provide a function for users to individually like Tweets is OK, and that’s one reason why the functionality exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written custom Twitter apps.  If I want users of my app to be able to "Like" a tweet, I call the Twitter API function that allows me to do so.

Comment: I accept this answer. But also, @Andy-Piper 's comment answered the "Why?" part of my question. Thanks to you both :)